# Equivalence of Hermitian Matrices and diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n{(\mathbb C)}$ be two hermitian matrices

I need to prove that (1) and (2) are equivalent

(1) There is a $g\in U_n$ so that $g^{-1}Ag$ and $g^{-1}Bg$ are both diagonal matrices
(2)AB is a hermitian matrix .

Since $g\in U_n$ we can say that $(g^{-1}Ag)^H = g^{-1} A^H g$ and $(g^{-1}Bg)^H = g^{-1} B^H g$

But how can I show the equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2):
$AB =g g^{-1} A g g^{-1} B g g^{-1} = g g^{-1} B g g^{-1} A g g^{-1} = BA$.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1): Since $AB= (AB)^* = B^* A^* = BA$ we see that $A,B$ commute, hence can be simultaneously diagonalised.

Comment: Thank your for the fast reply!